# Datatable not show data after update datasource

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the problem, after update the data-array (FileDto) no changes visible in the Datatable

I have testet put out the data in a ngFor, and it works fine.

In html:

```html
<ngx-datatable
  class="material striped"
  [rows]="fileDtos"
  [columnMode]="'force'"
  [rowHeight]="'auto'"
  [messages]="gridMessages"
>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="name" >
        <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
          <strong>{{ 'FILES.NAME' | translate}}</strong>
        </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Typescriptfile:

```
loadFiles(): void {
    this._fileService.getFiles(this.auftragId, false).subscribe(files => {
      this.fileDtos = files;
      this._fileService.getExcelFiles(this.auftragId).subscribe(filesexcel => {
        if ( filesexcel) {
          filesexcel.forEach(item => {
            this.fileDtos.push(item);
          });
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Dataobject:

```
export class FileDto {
    name: string;
    iconUrl: string;
    extension: string;
    created: Date | string;
    modified: Date | string;
}
```

I have no errormessages and not showing any data in the Datatable. Any Idea why?

Sample data:

```
{name: "Filename1.xlsm", iconUrl: null, extension: "", created: "2019-03-12T13:37:25.973", modified: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"}
{name: "Filename2.xlsm", iconUrl: null, extension: "", created: "2019-03-12T12:13:53.847", modified: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"}
{name: "Filename3.xlsm", iconUrl: null, extension: "", created: "2019-03-12T13:37:25.973", modified: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"}
```

Comment: Please share some sample data to work with.

Comment: please add your service, il your service is not dev for Angular, you can try this: `import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';....
 constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {  }....
 ....   {
        // Fix because angular is not aware of javascript callbacks
        this.ngZone.run(() => this.fileDtos.push(item);
      }`

Comment: @sgrillon I understand absolutly not what you mean... the service i use is a HttpClient service with observables-subscribe callbacks. see: https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

My test output in a ngFor work fine and put all my data out.
The only thing that doesn't work is the datatable itfelf.

Comment: @andreas, I understood your problem, you see well your data in this.fileDtos but your table does not take into account that `this.fileDtos` has been updated (no binding). With `this.ngZone.run` Angular detects the data change in `this.fileDtos` and does the binding in your table. Try change `filesexcel => {...}` by `filesexcel => { this.ngZone.run(() => {...} }`

Comment: @sgrillon,ok, little question make it a difference between this.fileDtos = files; and this.fileDtos.push(item); ? only the getFiles request witheout getExcelFiles() had worked.

Comment: you use `subscribe` in other `subscribe`, is it bad practice. See https://medium.com/@mohandere/rxjs-5-in-5-minutes-1c3b4ed0d8cc. before refactor your code, you can try `this.fileDtos = filesexcel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @sgrillon for the hint that subscribe in subscribe are a bad pracitse. Now its work fine.

Here's how I solved it with a forkJoin:

```
forkJoin(
      this._fileService.getFiles(this.auftragId, false), this._fileService.getExcelFiles(this.auftragId)
    ).subscribe((files) => {
      this.fileDtos = files[0].concat(files[1]);
    });
```